# How to relate 3 tables together in Bookshelf.js

Tags: javascript, bookshelf.js, knex.js

I've got the following tables:

- `books`
- `book_reviews`
- `users`

Here are the models that correspond to said tables:

```
const BookReview = require('./BookReview').model;
const User = require('./User').model;

module.exports.model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'books',

  user: function() {
    return this.hasOne(User, 'user_id');
  },

  reviews: function() {
    return this.hasMany(BookReview);
  }
});

module.exports.model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'book_reviews',

  user: function() {
    this.hasMany(User, 'user_id');
  }
});

module.exports.model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',

  reviews: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(BookReview, 'user_id');
  }
});
```

I'm looking up a Book and trying to fetch all reviews that it has, which it currently is doing with the following statement:

```
return Book.forge({
    id: req.params.id,
    type: req.params.type
  }).fetch({withRelated: ['reviews'], require: true}).then(function(book) {
    console.log(book.toJSON());
    return book;
  }).catch(function(err) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  });
```

};

And the output from `book.toJSON()` from above looks like:

Output from book.toJSON() from above:

```
{ id: 1,
  type: 'novel',
  slug: 'catcher-in-the-rye',
  user_id: 1,
  name: 'Catcher in the Rye',
  created_at: Tue Oct 04 2016 22:35:42 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  updated_at: Tue Oct 04 2016 22:35:42 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  reviews: 
   [ { id: 14,
       user_id: 2,
       book_id: 1,
       rating: 3,
       review: 'Test',
       created_at: Wed Oct 05 2016 20:47:34 GMT-0700 (PDT),
       updated_at: Wed Oct 05 2016 20:47:34 GMT-0700 (PDT) } ] }
```

But my intent is that each of the `reviews` would have a reference to the `users` table, which they currently don't. How can I link those together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you do:

```
return Book.forge({
    id: req.params.id,
    type: req.params.type
  }).fetch({withRelated: ['reviews', 'reviews.user'], require: true}).then(function(book) {
    console.log(book.toJSON());
    return book;
  }).catch(function(err) {
    throw new Error(err.message);
  });
```

?

Comment: I get the following: `Unhandled rejection Error: A valid target model must be defined for the book_reviews hasMany relation`

Comment: I think in your BookReview model `user` relation you need to put the review ID rather than the user ID: e.g. `this.hasMany(User, 'review_id')`. Other than that I don't see anything else wrong.

Comment: Ok so it actually turns out I had a circular dependency happening. I changed it so that it's: `module.exports.model = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'book_reviews',

  user: function() {
    const User = require('./User').model;
    return this.belongsTo(User, 'user_id');
  }` and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Ahh right. I usually use the registry plugin to avoid that: https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Model-Registry